# PieChart number parsing error after upgrading android studio 3.0.0

Tags: android, pie-chart, android-studio-3.0

After upgrading android studio 2.3 to 3.0, piChart start crashing, giving numberFormat exception int value "@2131165428". I checked all my code and response nowhere this type of value is coming.

I am not getting why it is showing this error, I checked in another studio, 2.3 is working fine, the only problem is with studio 3.0

[image: pieChart android studio 3.0 error]

Answer (score 2):

> [**`NumberFormatException`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) is an Exception that might be thrown
>   when you try to convert a String into a number, where that number
>   might be an int , a float , or any other Java numeric type.

**Problem**

`@2131165428`.

The above one is **`STRING`**. Whenever you converting to **`int`** then problem coming. You can't convert **`FORMAT`** due to **`@`**. For good approach use **`try-catch block`**.

```
  try 
    {
     // CODE HERE
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException exp) 
    {
    exp.printStackTrace(); // Call here, If any exception
    }
```

- You must remove **`STRING`** content from **`INTEGER`** .

Comment: already I explained, same code is working in studio 2.3, problem is with studio 3.0. try catch will not solve my problem,it will olny prevent crashes.

Comment: @RaviPrakashYadav I highly doubt it could ever work, on **any** OS version or IDE. `"@2131165428"` can **never** be a number.

Comment: @RaviPrakashYadav Please debug carefully. If `2.3` avoid this then I think Its a BUG. I guess sloppy mistake coming from your end.

Comment: @RaviPrakashYadav This rather seems to me being a programming error, like you failed to get the string resource properly. And it returns an id.